# Session lost after postback many times ASP.Net C# web form

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, webforms

i use session an ASP.Net C# web form to save user id that i get it from database when user log in

the user is data entry and he fill some form to upload it into database so there is a lot of  postback the problem is i lose my session after few postback

how to prevent this issue i need my session alive until user logout

my web page on hosting server

```
Session["EmpID"] = dt.Rows[0]["EmpID"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have couple of suggestions. Check for your session timeout, make sure you are not clearing your session in code anytime in-between and make sure your application pool is not recycling. If any of this does not work, make sure you have **SessionState** node in Web.Config file with mode and timeout attributes set. Also make sure you are getting the data while session is set. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, but how i can check the application pool is not recycling im using smarterasp.net hosting and about SessionState with time out 40 in web.config

Comment: Can you verify in your code that you have not written anything that could possibly cause the IIS to recycle. This happens you know, so try changing the mode attribute value to "StateServer" instead of "InProc" in the Config file and give it a go. In this case, it should work even if re-cycle occurs. But best is to make sure where your code causes the IIS recycle.